# View [ViewPathInController] not found only in linux environment

Tags: php, laravel

I was developing a laravel app in windows environment,
The app was working good, nothing is wrong, but after changing the environment to linux, some routes didn't work. I've got this message:

view [path] not found

even the views exists and works fine in windows. 
I tried a lot of solution, but nothing worked. 
Solutions that I tried:

clearing cache
changing routes name
removing LaravelCollective/html and re require it ...

but none of these solutions worked. 
Any help?

Comment: There are issues with uppercase and lowercase in linux

Comment: You have to provide more information. Start with post related code from route file, controller method, error logs.

Comment: In my controller: public function chekcHistory(){ 
... 
return view('humanr.hoursRecup.history)->with();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linux is sensitive to uppercase and lowercase. 
The problem was: instead of writing humanR.recupHourh
I wrote humanr.recupHours.
Issue solved.